# Critical temperature Asus n551jx

Tags: temperature, nvidia-geforce

I got this asus n551jx machine, which comes with a pretty good setup of GPU (GTX950m), and CPU too (i7 4720hq). Therefore gaming is not a problem, and it's quite enjoyable! The only thing that scaries me is the temperature that the laptop get. Around 96C° for the CPU and around 85C° for the CPU...measured with CPUID monitor. Is that high??(yes I guess), what could be the solution??

I thank you for your help, looking forward for a proper solution.

ciao

Comment: Also, already 4 youtube fullHD videos together push the machine up to the  same temp....

Answer (score -1):

I have the same Pc with identical setup, and I've the same problem.  I've asked for some help around the web and I've got the solution (or at least part of it). Our Pc is a really strong and efficient machine, in terms of performances, but unfortunately it is not that efficient in terms of heating exchange. The only way I've managed to work with a lower temperature (talking ofc about hard tasks for example with gaming),was going on *battery save options* and look around there. *I've created a new profile* (stock one is balanced profile), *called it "gaming"* (but you can name it whatever you want), ***and min/maxed some options there finding the best solution, I've put on the line "**CPU performance**" to work at 80%***, now the Cpu frequency downgraded from 3.7 Ghz to around 2.9 Ghz and my Temperature dropped as a consequence of about 20 degrees ( going around 60-70 Degrees Celsius) and dropping aroung 5 to 6 FPS in games (not that many). Hope this helps, with that said I'm a little bit disappointed for this inconvenient, because i know that downgrading the CPU it is not the best solution but at least you won't income in severe complications with the risk of ruining your machine forever.